# How do I implement a C# Thrift service and consume it with a Silverlight client?

Tags: c#, silverlight, thrift

I'm current looking at Thrift to use as a RPC framework for our apps (mostly written in C# and Silverlight).  I've come as far as implementing a service and consuming it from a C# console app (using a socket as transport).

For the C# server side code my code looked like: (basically copying the tutorials included with the source code)

```
MyServiceHandler handler = new MyServiceHandler();
MyService.Processor processor = new MyService.Processor(handler);
TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
TServer server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport);
server.Serve();
```

For the client side code it looked like:

```
TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
MyService.Client client = new MyService.Client(protocol);
transport.Open();
client.SomeServiceCall();
```

However, we will be consuming the service from a Silverlight client, and unfortunately there is no support for sockets in Silverlight for Thrift. I assume I'm forced to use HTTP communication between the client and service, using Thrift's C# THttpClient and THttpHandler classes? I could not find any examples of how to do this out there, can anyone point me in the right direction? Some example server and client side code would be appreciated.

Comment: With Silverlight, *and it's many and varied security considerations*, the pattern is usually to call exterior services from the Silverlight Web host/service or another WCF or RIA service on your hosting. This means your Silverlight app has a single port of call for any services. Can you provide any sample code?

Comment: I added some sample code

Comment: what does MyService look like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this issue was already addressed by [this guy](http://damianblog.com/2011/01/11/generating-silverlight-windows-phone-compatible-thrift-proxies/). According to [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1037), the fix is available in Thrift 0.9. You can either try [this snapshot](https://builds.apache.org/job/Thrift/353/) (note that, as it's not a final release, it might not be stable) or you can apply [this patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12506158/THRIFT-1037_Proposed_changes_to_support_Silverlight_Windows_Phone_and_AsyncCTP.patch) to the 0.8 release.

Comment: Thanks npclaudiu, I'm already making use of Thirft 0.9 that has his  patch included, I just don't have a clue how to use it; hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by now you would have understood, there is no direct way of communicating from Silverlight to the Cassandra database either using Thrift or any other clients.

I have one simple option related to this. Write a Silverlight enabled web service and consume it from the client.

For example, on the server side you can have a web service which does insert/update/read etc., like this. I just managed to pull out some code which we use for our project. Hope this helps.

```
using Apache.Cassandra;
using Thrift.Protocol;
using Thrift.Transport;

namespace CassandraWebLibrary
{
    public class MyDb
    {
        String _host;
        int _port;
        String _keyspace;
        bool _isConnected;
        TTransport _transport = null;
        Apache.Cassandra.Cassandra.Client _client = null;
        String columnFamily = "ColumnFamilyName";
        public VazhikaattiDB(String host, int port, String keyspace)
        {
            _host = host;
            _port = port;
            _keyspace = keyspace;
            _isConnected = false;
        }

        public bool Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                _transport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket(_host, _port));
                TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(_transport);
                _client = new Apache.Cassandra.Cassandra.Client(protocol);

                _transport.Open();

                _client.set_keyspace(_keyspace);

                _isConnected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
            return _isConnected;
        }

        public bool Close()
        {
            if (_transport.IsOpen)
                _transport.Close();
            _isConnected = false;
            return true;
        }

        public bool InsertData(Send your data as parameters here)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Column> list = new List<Column>();
                string strKey = keyvalue;

                #region Inserting into Coulmn family
                 List<Byte> valbytes = new List<byte>(BitConverter.GetBytes(value)); //You might have to pad this with more bytes to make it length of 8 bytes

                Column doublecolumn1 = new Column()
                {
                    Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("column1"),
                    Timestamp = timestampvalue,
                    Value = valbytes.ToArray()
                };
                list.Add(doublecolumn1);

                Column stringcolumn2 = new Column()
                {
                    Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("column2"),
                    Timestamp = timestampvalue,
                    Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("StringValue")
                };
                list.Add(stringcolumn2);

                Column timecolumn3 = new Column()
                {
                    Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("column3"),
                    Timestamp = timestampvalue,
                    Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
                };
                list.Add(timecolumn3);
                #endregion


                ColumnParent columnParent = new ColumnParent();
                columnParent.Column_family = columnFamily;

                Byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey);
                foreach (Column column in list)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _client.insert(key, columnParent, column, ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        log.Error(e.ToString());
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        public List<YourReturnObject> GetData(parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                ColumnParent columnParent = new ColumnParent();
                columnParent.Column_family = columnFamily;
                DateTime curdate = startdate;

                IndexExpression indExprsecondkey = new IndexExpression();
                indExprsecondkey.Column_name = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("column");
                indExprsecondkey.Op = IndexOperator.EQ;

                List<Byte> valbytes = PadLeftBytes((int)yourid, 8);
                indExprsecondkey.Value = valbytes.ToArray();
                indExprList.Add(indExprsecondkey);


                IndexClause indClause = new IndexClause()
                {
                    Expressions = indExprList,
                    Count = 1000,
                    Start_key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")
                };

                SlicePredicate slice = new SlicePredicate()
                {
                    Slice_range = new SliceRange()
                    {
                        //Start and Finish cannot be null 
                        Start = new byte[0],
                        Finish = new byte[0],
                        Count = 1000,
                        Reversed = false
                    }
                };
                List<KeySlice> keyslices = _client.get_indexed_slices(columnParent, indClause, slice, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
                foreach (KeySlice ks in keyslices)
                {
                    String stringcolumnvalue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cl.Column.Value);
                    double doublevalue= (Double)BitConverter.ToDouble(cl.Column.Value); 
                    long timeticks = BitConverter.ToInt64(cl.Column.Value, 0);
                    DateTime dtcolumntime = new DateTime(timeticks);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }

            return yourdatalist;
        }


    }
}
```

Now the above class can be used by your webservice, which in turn will be used by Silverlight. Btw, you'll have to take care of other silverlight issues like size of data to be downloaded from server/webservice etc.,
FYI, our client service of Cassandra runs on port 9160..

Comment: Hi Muthu, doesn't writing an intermediate web service defeat the object of writing an optimised Thrift service?  My thinking is that it should be possible to communicate with the Thrift service via HTTP.

Comment: I don't think so. The option specified by you looks like as if I am ready to give a client script like javascript, silverlight etc., to directly access the database (may be with all security etc.,). Majority of the databases do not give such direct access IMO.